# Why index of check is not working

Tags: jquery

I have got names as

```
755_KK_0_KK_0tab1_checkbox  
755_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab1_checkbox  
755_KK_0_KK_0tab2_checkbox  
755_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab2_checkbox
```

I am checking if a string has **tab1** in it or not this way

```
var vendoritemsdata = [
  {"name": "755_KK_0_KK_0tab1_checkbox"}, 
  {"name": "755_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab1_checkbox"},
  {"name": "755_KK_0_KK_0tab2_checkbox"},
  {"name": "755_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab2_checkbox"}
]

var value = 1;
var temp_arry = [];

for (var i = 0; i < vendoritemsdata.length; i++) {
    var itemname = vendoritemsdata.indexOf("tab" + value);
    if (itemname === -1) {
        var namesss = vendoritemsdata[i].name;
        temp_arry.push(namesss);

    }
}
alert(temp_arry);
```

But inspite of the check for **tab1** or **tab2** ---

why its pushing all the elemets to the array ??

http://jsfiddle.net/ya665q7y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test it against the name of the current item(in the iteration) so

```
for (var i = 0; i < vendoritemsdata.length; i++) {
    var itemname = vendoritemsdata[i].name.indexOf("tab" + value);
    if (itemname === -1) {
        var namesss = vendoritemsdata[i].name;
        temp_arry.push(namesss);

    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/82sb32cx/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use name of element like,

```
var itemname = vendoritemsdata[i].name.indexOf("tab" + value);
```

Code,

```
for (var i = 0; i < vendoritemsdata.length; i++) {
    var itemname = vendoritemsdata[i].name.indexOf("tab" + value);
    // here you need name for ----^---^--- each element and check indexOf
    if (itemname === -1) {
        var namesss = vendoritemsdata[i].name;
        temp_arry.push(namesss);
    }
}
```

```js
var vendoritemsdata = [{
    "name": "755_KK_0_KK_0tab1_checkbox"

}, {
    "name": "755_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab1_checkbox"

}, {
    "name": "755_KK_0_KK_0tab2_checkbox"

}, {
    "name": "755_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab2_checkbox"

}]

var value = 1;
var temp_arry = [];

for (var i = 0; i < vendoritemsdata.length; i++) {
    var itemname = vendoritemsdata[i].name.indexOf("tab" + value);
    if (itemname === -1) {
        var namesss = vendoritemsdata[i].name;
        temp_arry.push(namesss);
    }
}

alert(temp_arry);
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not check on the name try this:

```
var itemname = vendoritemsdata[i].name.indexOf("tab"+value);
```

like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<vendoritemsdata.length;i++) {
  var itemname = vendoritemsdata[i].name.indexOf("tab"+value);
  if(itemname === -1) {
    var namesss = vendoritemsdata[i].name;
    temp_arry.push(namesss);
  }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ya665q7y/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you put the jQuery tag on your question, you may consider the following solution as well:

```
filteredArray = jQuery.grep(inputArray, function (element) {
    return a.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 //this assumes elements are strings (not objects)
});
```

Example with your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/hzndmyzj/